# Specific hierarchy geography

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, sql-server-2014

I have a table geography with three levels

[image]

I need to display the level3 only for level2 = France, Benelux and for the other countries level2 = level 3

Result Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Select
  level1,
  level2,
  Case when level2 in ('France', 'Benelux') then level3 else level2 end as level3
 from geography;
```

Answer (score 3):

if your country name fixed than you can use below query for your result

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    LVL1,
    LVL2,
    CASE WHEN LVL2 IN ('FRANCE','BENELUX') THEN LVL3 ELSE LVL2 END LVL  
FROM geography
```